# Ubuntu 15.04 big icons in app store

Tags: icons, 15.04

Why are the icons in ubuntu app store big on ubuntu 15.04? on Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS is everything fine

http://s4.postimg.org/872fvqhy5/Slika_zaslona_2015_06_24_12_46_12.png